# save a variable to a file on the terminal in Linux same way in matlab save()

Tags: linux

Is there way to save a variable to a file on the terminal in Linux same way in matlab  `save(filename,variables)` function? For example I have in matlab

```
seg=sampleframe(:,1)   # this a 20 sn segment from an audio file
seg_file=fullfile(destination_dir,'000000001.mat')  # this is a filename i created
save(seg_file,'seg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While shell variables can't typically contain binary data, you can save their values to a file; the simplest example would be:

```
seg=$(seq 1 100)
printf '%s\n' "$seg" 000000001.mat
```

Above, I'm populating the `seg` variable with the output from a command (the numeric sequence 1..100), then asking the `printf` command to print that string, followed by a newline. The shell redirects that value into the named file.

Comment: I used python`s savemat in a script instead because i had a time limits to finish my project , but I will use your answer if i need to do it on terminal,  thank you!